# How to fix getResourceID Not found issue in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there anyone here had an experience with having an error when getting the resourceId in the context?

I am using `context.getResourceID()` but it says a `NotFoundException` Error.

I am fetching a layout resource just to be specific.

I already tried cleaning and rebuilding it but I haven't got any luck.

By the way I'm creating a library to be used for creating an Adobe Native Extension.

Here is my sample code:

```
public class RunVRFunction implements FREFunction {
    public static final String TAG = "RunVRFunction";

    @Override
    public FREObject call(FREContext extContext, FREObject[] args) {

        int layoutID;
        Intent i = new Intent(extContext.getActivity(), Main2Activity.class);

        try {
            layoutID = extContext.getResourceId("layout.activity_main2");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf("getResourceID() failed with error:\n\"%s\"\n",
                    e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(extContext.getActivity(), "getResourceID() failed" +
                    e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }

        i.putExtra("layoutID", layoutID);

        try {
            extContext.getActivity().startActivity(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf("startActivity() failed with error:\n\"%s\"\n",
                    e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(extContext.getActivity(), "startActivity() failed: " +
                    e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the error in logcat:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: layout.activity_main2
```

Thanks.

Comment: @MDNaseemAshraf thank you sir. I already updated my question :)

Comment: try this extContext.getResourceId(R.layout.activity_main2)

Comment: @phnmnn did try it sir but same issue